# Java How To Hide Columns Names In JTable

Tags: java

I dont want to cancel any columns. I just dont want to see column names. So normaly i use the JTable with scroll pane. And i use this code:

```
scrollPane.setViewportView(table);
```

But when i use this i cant hide the column names. So i tryed something else and i fine this code:

```
scrollPane.setColumnHeaderView(table);
```

This does what i need but when i use this code ,i cant see the all table and there is no scroll bar.

So basicly i want a table with scroll bar and with out columns name. Im sure its easy but i cant find it.

Comment: Would calling `table.setTableHeader(null);` work for you, if you use the first option?

Comment: @maloomeister thanks alot. Thats what i need.